# Error with Ionic/React when using a Swiper

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I m trying to use a swiper component in a ionic react app, whenever i use i get the same message about hook calls even if i m not using them, i have tried creating a default sidemenu app and adding a simple siwper with one ionic card and i still get the same error.

the code for App.tsx is:

```
    import { IonApp, IonRouterOutlet, IonSplitPane, setupIonicReact } from '@ionic/react';
import { IonReactRouter } from '@ionic/react-router';
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import Page from './pages/Page';

/* Core CSS required for Ionic components to work properly */
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';

/* Basic CSS for apps built with Ionic */
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';

/* Optional CSS utils that can be commented out */
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';

/* Theme variables */
import './theme/variables.css';

setupIonicReact();

const App: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <IonApp>
      <IonReactRouter>
        <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
          <Menu />
          <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
            <Route path="/" exact={true}>
              <Redirect to="/page/Inbox" />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/page/:name" exact={true}>
              <Page />
            </Route>
          </IonRouterOutlet>
        </IonSplitPane>
      </IonReactRouter>
    </IonApp>
  );
};

export default App;
```

the code for Page.tsx is:

```
import { IonCard, IonCardContent,IonButtons,IonMenuButton, IonGrid, IonRow, IonCol, IonCardHeader, IonCardTitle, IonContent, IonHeader, IonImg, IonPage, IonSlides, IonTitle, IonToolbar } from '@ionic/react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router';
import ExploreContainer from '../components/ExploreContainer';
import './Page.css';
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react';
const Page: React.FC = () => {
const { name } = useParams<{ name: string; }>();

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonButtons slot="start">
            <IonMenuButton />
          </IonButtons>
          <IonTitle>{name}</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>

      <IonContent fullscreen>
        <IonHeader collapse="condense">
          <IonToolbar>
            <IonTitle size="large">{name}</IonTitle>
          </IonToolbar>
        </IonHeader>
        <ExploreContainer name={name} />
        <Swiper>
          <SwiperSlide>
            <IonCard>
              <IonCardTitle>
                Card Title 1
              </IonCardTitle>
              <IonCardContent>
                Card content 1
              </IonCardContent>
            </IonCard>
          </SwiperSlide>
          </Swiper>
      </IonContent>
    </IonPage>
  );
};

export default Page;
```

and i get this error:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
at resolveDispatcher (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3465)
at useState (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:3495)
at :8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:14677
at renderWithHooks (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:91895)
at updateForwardRef (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:93917)
at beginWork (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:95905)
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80845)
at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80894)
at invokeGuardedCallback (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:80954)
at beginWork$1 (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:100696)
at performUnitOfWork (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:99532)
at workLoopSync (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:99469)
at renderRootSync (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:99435)
at performSyncWorkOnRoot (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:99052)
at :8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:88305
at unstable_runWithPriority (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:111487)
at runWithPriority$1 (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:88251)
at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:88300)
at flushSyncCallbackQueue (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:88288)
at unbatchedUpdates (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:99199)
at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:102708)
at Object.render (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:102791)
at Module.<anonymous> (:8100/static/js/main.chunk.js:991)
at Module../src/index.tsx (:8100/static/js/main.chunk.js:1084)
at __webpack_require__ (:8100/static/js/bundle.js:857)
at fn (:8100/static/js/bundle.js:151)
at Object.1 (:8100/static/js/main.chunk.js:1834)
at __webpack_require__ (:8100/static/js/bundle.js:857)
at checkDeferredModules (:8100/static/js/bundle.js:46)
at Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push] (:8100/static/js/bundle.js:33)
at :8100/static/js/main.chunk.js:1
index.js:1 

The above error occurred in the <Swiper> component:
at http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:14677:73
at ion-content
at ReactComponent (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:53996:7)
at IonContent
at div
at PageManager (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54707:5)
at IonPageInternal (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54779:5)
at IonPage
at Page (http://localhost:8100/static/js/main.chunk.js:1215:69)
at Route (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:106503:29)
at ViewLifeCycleManager (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:55907:5)
at ion-router-outlet
at ReactComponent (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:53996:7)
at IonRouterOutlet
at StackManager (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:51654:5)
at IonRouterOutletContainer (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54887:5)
at IonRouterOutlet
at ion-split-pane
at ReactComponent (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:53996:7)
at IonSplitPane
at NavManager (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:56133:5)
at IonRouterInner (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:51901:5)
at C (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:106760:37)
at Router (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:106134:30)
at IonReactRouter (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:52200:5)
at ion-app
at ReactComponent (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:53996:7)
at IonApp
at <anonymous> (http://localhost:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:54662:5)
at App

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
react-dom.development.js:11340 

Menu: must have a "content" element to listen for drag events on.
console.<computed> @ index.js:1
VM11:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object.4043 (<anonymous>:2:13168)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at Object.8048 (<anonymous>:2:9496)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at Object.8641 (<anonymous>:2:1379)
at r (<anonymous>:2:306599)
at <anonymous>:2:315627
at <anonymous>:2:324225
at <anonymous>:2:324229
at HTMLIFrameElement.e.onload (:8100/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:104946)
```

Comment: this is a simple enough project that you should be able to post some code?

Comment: Page.tsx I posted, the only other file is app.tsx which Is the default one in a ionic sidemenu project(i have not modified it)